# Unexpected error when trying to install conda environment from .yaml file

Tags: python-3.x, conda, virtual-environment

I am trying to install a conda environment in WSL2 from a .yaml file, the instructions for the installation saying the first step is to run the following command:

```
conda env create -f devtools/conda-envs/ael-test.yaml
```

After the WSL2 terminal collects the package metadata and solves the environment, it encounters an error, which I don't really know how to solve. I run the command above from the base environment, from the directory where /devtools/conda-ens/ael-test.yaml is located.

```
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done
Preparing transaction: failed

# >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ERROR REPORT <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/gheorghe/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1079, in __call__
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/gheorghe/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda_env/cli/main.py", line 80, in do_call
        exit_code = getattr(module, func_name)(args, parser)
      File "/home/gheorghe/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda_env/cli/main_create.py", line 141, in execute
        result[installer_type] = installer.install(prefix, pkg_specs, args, env)
      File "/home/gheorghe/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda_env/installers/conda.py", line 59, in install
        unlink_link_transaction.execute()
      File "/home/gheorghe/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/core/link.py", line 245, in execute
        self.verify()
      File "/home/gheorghe/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/common/io.py", line 88, in decorated
        return f(*args, **kwds)
      File "/home/gheorghe/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/core/link.py", line 222, in verify
        self.prepare()
      File "/home/gheorghe/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/core/link.py", line 211, in prepare
        grps = self._prepare(self.transaction_context, stp.target_prefix,
      File "/home/gheorghe/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/core/link.py", line 288, in _prepare
        packages_info_to_link = tuple(read_package_info(prec, pcrec)
      File "/home/gheorghe/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/core/link.py", line 288, in <genexpr>
        packages_info_to_link = tuple(read_package_info(prec, pcrec)
      File "/home/gheorghe/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/gateways/disk/read.py", line 89, in read_package_info
        package_metadata = read_package_metadata(epd)
      File "/home/gheorghe/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/gateways/disk/read.py", line 144, in read_package_metadata
        data = json.loads(f.read())
      File "/home/gheorghe/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 357, in loads
        return _default_decoder.decode(s)
      File "/home/gheorghe/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
        obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
      File "/home/gheorghe/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
        raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
    json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

`$ /home/gheorghe/anaconda3/bin/conda-env create -f devtools/conda-envs/ael-test.yaml`

  environment variables:
                 CIO_TEST=<not set>
  CONDA_AUTO_UPDATE_CONDA=false
        CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV=base
                CONDA_EXE=/home/gheorghe/anaconda3/bin/conda
             CONDA_PREFIX=/home/gheorghe/anaconda3
    CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER=(base)
         CONDA_PYTHON_EXE=/home/gheorghe/anaconda3/bin/python
               CONDA_ROOT=/home/gheorghe/anaconda3
              CONDA_SHLVL=1
           CURL_CA_BUNDLE=<not set>
                     PATH=/home/gheorghe/anaconda3/bin:/home/gheorghe/.vscode-server/bin/f4af3cb
                          f5a99787542e2a30fe1fd37cd644cc31f/bin:/home/gheorghe/anaconda3/bin:/ho
                          me/gheorghe/anaconda3/condabin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbi
                          n:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/mnt/c/Program Files
                          /WindowsApps/Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_1.11.2921.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe:
                          /mnt/c/Program Files/copasi.org/COPASI 4.29.228/bin:/mnt/c/Windows/sys
                          tem32:/mnt/c/Windows:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/mnt/c/Windows/Syste
                          m32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/OpenSSH:/mnt/c/Prog
                          ram Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine
                          Components/DAL:/mnt/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine
                          Components/DAL:/mnt/c/Program Files/NVIDIA Corporation/NVIDIA
                          NvDLISR:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/NVIDIA
                          Corporation/PhysX/Common:/mnt/c/Program Files/Mullvad VPN/resources:/m
                          nt/c/WINDOWS/system32:/mnt/c/WINDOWS:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:/mnt
                          /c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/Ope
                          nSSH:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Propellerhead
                          Software/ReWire:/mnt/c/Program Files/Common Files/Propellerhead
                          Software/ReWire:/mnt/c/Program Files/NCBI/blast-2.12.0+/bin:/mnt/c/Use
                          rs/gheor/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin:/mnt/c/Users/ghe
                          or/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/snap/bin
       REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=<not set>
            SSL_CERT_FILE=<not set>

     active environment : base
    active env location : /home/gheorghe/anaconda3
            shell level : 1
       user config file : /home/gheorghe/.condarc
 populated config files : /home/gheorghe/.condarc
          conda version : 4.10.3
    conda-build version : 3.21.5
         python version : 3.8.11.final.0
       virtual packages : __linux=5.10.16.3=0
                          __glibc=2.31=0
                          __unix=0=0
                          __archspec=1=x86_64
       base environment : /home/gheorghe/anaconda3  (writable)
      conda av data dir : /home/gheorghe/anaconda3/etc/conda
  conda av metadata url : None
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
          package cache : /home/gheorghe/anaconda3/pkgs
                          /home/gheorghe/.conda/pkgs
       envs directories : /home/gheorghe/anaconda3/envs
                          /home/gheorghe/.conda/envs
               platform : linux-64
             user-agent : conda/4.10.3 requests/2.26.0 CPython/3.8.11 Linux/5.10.16.3-microsoft-standard-WSL2 ubuntu/20.04.3 glibc/2.31
                UID:GID : 1000:1000
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False


An unexpected error has occurred. Conda has prepared the above report.

If submitted, this report will be used by core maintainers to improve
future releases of conda.
```

Edit:

This is the .yaml file:

```
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - pytorch
dependencies:
  - python
  - pip

  - numpy
  - scipy
  - scikit-learn

  - qcelemental
  - openbabel

  - matplotlib
  - seaborn

  - mlflow

  - pytorch
  - torchvision

  - lark-parser
  - cython

  - pip:
    - torchani
    - "git+https://github.com/RMeli/mdanalysis.git@develop#egg=MDAnalysis&subdirectory=package"

  - black
  - flake8
  - mypy
  - isort

  - pytest
  - pytest-xdist
  - pytest-cov
  - codecov
```

Comment: Please add or link to the YAML. Otherwise, this looks like a package may have been corrupted (not sure). You could also try rerunning the command, but with verbosity turned up (`-vv` or `-vvv`) to see exactly what package it chokes on.

Comment: @merv I've added the .yaml file. When I turn the verbosity up, I get the same error, but with this failure in the debug:

Preparing transaction: ...working... TRACE conda.core.package_cache_data:_check_writable(261): package cache directory '/home/gheorghe/.conda/pkgs' does not exist
failed

Comment: Neither the YAML nor the `conda env create` command provide a name for the new environment. Possibly could be an issue, especially if running with **base** activated.

Comment: @merv there is a name in the yaml, I just didn't add it sorry.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem in your environment, I managed to install it, getting

```
Successfully built MDAnalysis
Installing collected packages: msgpack, tqdm, mrcfile, mmtf-python, gsd, fasteners, biopython, GridDataFormats, torchani, MDAnalysis
Successfully installed GridDataFormats-1.0.1 MDAnalysis-2.6.0.dev0 biopython-1.81 fasteners-0.18 gsd-3.1.1 mmtf-python-1.1.3 mrcfile-1.4.3 msgpack-1.0.5 torchani-2.2.3 tqdm-4.66.1

done
#
# To activate this environment, use
#
#     $ conda activate ael
```

in the end.

The problem you encountering is probably related to https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/9590
which has a workaround

```
sudo rm -r ~/.condarc
```

or editing the ~/.condarc like https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/9590#issuecomment-1003211237